# project tango / arcore area mapping

Tags: google-project-tango, point-clouds, arcore

As we know, ARCore has all but replaced project tango but I have some research projects in mind that involve area mapping, therefore I have few questions regarding tango and ARCore.

1. For Area mapping, tango produces more precise and denser point-cloud information than ARCore, therefore if I want to "area-map", a Tango device would be better for me. Is this right?
2. The SDK for ARCore and Tango are the same thing and therefore support for its methods, documentation etc. are still effectively available for Tango with the ARCore SDK?
3. I don't yet have an ARCore or Tango device (although I played around with Tango a bit a few years ago), so if the Tango SDK is different, where do I get it now there is no Tango support page?
4. Am thinking of getting a Zenfone AR for my Tango project. Any reason why not?

Comment: As far as I know Tango is not supported anymore, and it was replaced by ARCore, so I would suggest not investing in it.

Answer (score 1):

1. A Tango would be better as it has area recognition (recall). You can plot an area using the Tango, save as an .adf and then reload that using Area Learning. ARCore has a Visual Positioning Service in beta, which sounds very similar to Area Learning, but it has been in development for well over a year.
2. The SDK's share similarities, but are different.
3. You can find the archive SDK if you google "Tango Examples", here is the Unity one https://github.com/googlearchive/tango-examples-unity
4. ZenPhone AR is your best bet as it is the only device to support both ARCore and Tango. So you have the flexibility to switch around if needed.

Good luck with your research. As others have said Tango still has it's uses, but doesn't really have any commercial support anymore. I'm still using it though.

Answer (score 0):

What is your project trying to do?  I think there are only a few specific use cases left for tango.

If you want customers to download an app, you won't get that with tango - no-one uses the devices.

If you are using the kit for a booth/art exhibit/etc.. where you own and let people use a device, it can be a useful cheap way of doing handheld AR.  But there are other stronger methods for working with depth data in a lot of those cases.  And lots of optical options can achieve similar results too.

So essentially, use ARCore if that is at all an option for your project.

Comment: I am definitely not interested in making an app for download and not interested in the AR aspect of these devices. Essentially I want to use the point-cloud data to create a 3D area map of the interior of a building. ARCore devices produce sparse point-clouds compared with tango ones don't they?

Comment: Can't answer you authoritatively, but there will certainly be differences because Tango would give you a depth sensors view and ARCore will be using optical only.

If you just need a 3d map, and not the AR aspects, you'd may get better results from offline photogrammetry, like the one from AutoDesk.

Check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnXehd7oxto for an example of the quality offline photogrammetry can achieve.

https://sketchfab.com/models/08b2e2da52b6459b8059bfc6a2f4eeb1 shows a tango scan - this is what you get out of the box without having to manually work on the result.

Comment: Or for a cooler tango example https://sketchfab.com/models/d41cc890e9f74fe9bc460877abe1547f?ref=related shows a well done scan (open constructor)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I could be wrong but the photogrammetry example is capturing from a static position, just rotating on the spot? Whereas Tango combines the captured point-clouds with their "Pose" information, allowing you to move around a building capturing lots of areas and stitching the point-clouds together. Of course I could just move the photo device lots taking new captures at each new position but this is awkward and time consuming.

Comment: Not sure for that specific example, it was probabbly taken from lots of positions, the video just doesn't move around.
"move the photo device around taking lots of new captures at each position" - that's exactly what you'd be doing with tango or offline photogrammetry.  Tango is taking depth photos at 5hz and doing the work for you, while using a camera you take them yourself (use a timer if you don't wanna keep pressing the button) and doing the processing offline after.

Basically, i'd say tango could be useful for you, but you'll get much better results, for more manual workthe other way