# Real World Object Recognition With Augmented Reality

Tags: android, augmented-reality

The Android App that I am developing, should recognize a real-world object (a lamp in my use case) with a label/tag/picture on it.
This is how I imagine it would work:

- User point to the Object using app, tags/labels the object and saves it.
- Later when the user points to the object through App it should identify the object and display the tag/label.

Could someone please point me to the resources/SDK needed or a sample app with a similar feature?

Comment: Do you need to detect a specific lamp or distinguish between two similar lamps? What user action are you trying to do to turn off and turn on the lamp? How are you communicating to the switch to turn on/off the lamp? Do you need to show virtual objects in the view?

Comment: For now, "detect" a single lamp. Yes, I will turn on/off the lamp. Lamp's SDK will help me turn on/off the lamp. Yes that virtual object could be a Slider/toggle button

Comment: Have you tried any of the available SDK? AR Core, Wikitude, Vuforia etc?

Comment: Tried Vuforia's object recognition feature. I couldn't get it to work as it requires a paper sheet on the background of the object in order to get detected.

Comment: So you didn't try a custom [image target](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Image-Target-Guide) provided a [suitable target](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Optimizing-Target-Detection-and-Tracking-Stability#optimize). While the sample shows a 3D teapot, you should be able to trigger/enable/make visible the switch on detection.

Comment: In my case, I need to detect a lamp. I didn't try an image target.

Comment: I have the similar you case did you get it to work?

Comment: @MorrisonChang what you are suggesting here requires image target, however in the real world detecting a lamp or a IoT device and carrying an image target is probably not a scalable solution. In my use case, what i want  is to detect an IoT device, and take an action

Comment: @BigO Honestly True arbitrary 3D object recognition is hard, while Google Goggles/Lens is can identify the Eiffel Tower, I'm not sure how well it could identify a specific type of Ikea lamp, given that new ones show up all the time. If trying to identifying a lamp as located in the northeast corner of a room then look into [project tango / area core mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50075491/295004) with the understanding that Project Tango is no longer supported. Tagging objects with indicia/barcodes would be easier to implement.

Comment: @BigO Should you wish to attempt indoor area mapping without Project Tango look to Bluetooth beacons and [802.11mc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11mc) which appears to be in [Android Pie](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-rtt).